# MySQL SQLSTATE root and normal login not function

Tags: server, permissions, 22.04, login, mysql

Hello guys i have little problem with MySQL and Pterodactyl. When i try add databases i got this problem.

`There was an error while trying to connect to the host or while executing a query: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'Kjumecz'@'192.168.0.185' to database 'mysql' (Connection: dynamic, SQL: SELECT 1 FROM dual)"`

[image]
[image]

And i IDK what do with this i try search on google but everythink what i found is

> "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES"

thats what i do but nothing changed how to connect or repair mysql to catch a databases in pterodactyl server manager app

[image]